# SWT Setting Column Height or insert new line

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I currently have a Table [org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table]  with several TableColumns; however, due to UI space restrictions I have a bit of an issue.

Lets say for example I had a table column named "Target User" and this couldn't be named anything else AND the whole display "Target User" had to be displayed.  Now lets say I also have several other Table Columns with the same problems.

I was hoping I could add a new line or do something to set the height of the column so it could be  Target \n User and I could save some width that way.  However, \n does not seem to work in org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableColumn.setText  , nor does html.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, this (the "`\n`" within a `Label` of a `TableColumn`) only works in Linux, not Windows.

See [bug 97077](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=97077) (2005!)

> Linux/GTK implementation of table column can be easily made multiline inserting "`\n`" into text - should work in current implementations.
>   Windows implementation for this would be very tricky. In Win32 programming
>   people either replace table control or table header control to get this functionality or create all kind of tricks to full ListView32 window to allow multiliner.

Comment: Well that explains the why, and I guess also means that they have no intent on fixing this any time soon....