# Multiline Table header / Multiline TabItem text

Tags: swt, multiline, tabitem

I migrate application from Swing to SWT and cannot find out how to make table headers in SWT multiline and also TabItems to have multiline text. In Swing it was not problem but in SWT no way. For table header [I found that on linux it is working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359295/swt-setting-column-height-or-insert-new-line) but I need it for windows. I tried `\n` and `<br>` but nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You might find this useful:

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/MultilineTablecell.htm

You need to override some events generated when the table is painted and modify the cell size according to the number of text lines in the cell. I'm not sure if the events are same for header cells though. Suggest you try it out and post a comment back here :-)